# Ubuntu/Xubuntu install freeze

Tags: installation, windows, xubuntu, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I've been trying to install (dual boot) Ubuntu on my HP PC, [Link to my specs (click here)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03029064&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5151854&prodTypeId=12454)

I've tried to install Ubuntu with both USB and DVD, same result. The installer will launch, it will load, but then all will freeze in the middle of the loading.

Well, I thought it was something wrong with Ubuntu, so I tried Xubuntu instead. Same thing, the installer will go to the loading screen, but then, it'll just freeze at the point where the "loading cursor" appears.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: On my machine, loading from USB is slow, very slow. Have you been patient enough?

Comment: Well, I waited like 1 hour... :D

Answer (score 0):

When you stated you tried to install via usb, do you mean a usb dvd drive or something like [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)?

I suggest you try running 'check media for faults' on startup with the media before trying to install and check that returns ok.

If you tried installing using a burnt dvd, trying installing with a burnt cd (though it looks like you have a blueray player that should accept both).

I take it you are trying to install the latest version of ubuntu (12) or an older version?

Comment: Yes, I  mean things like Pendrive Linux. Yep, latest one I'm trying to install... And as already said, same with Xubuntu.

Comment: Did you manage to run 'check disc for defects'? Did that return ok? This is very strange, I take it you have been starting the install process by booting the computer with the cd in, not trying to install ubuntu after you have booted into windows (I believe you can do that in certain circumstances wubi etc) Can you link where you got the iso from?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop From the official website. And yes, I started the installation by booting the computer with the DVD in. Not Wubi at all.